# How to localize data coming from the backend with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm building an angular app with [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). It's working nicely. Now I'm starting to have data coming from my backend(firebase), for which I will have translations.

What is the correct way of displaying localized data from a model? I've not yet settled on the data format, so either it will be something like:

```
{
  'title_fr': 'mon titre',
  'title_en': 'my title',
  'title_de': 'mein Titel',
  'description_fr' : '....'
  //...
}
```

either something like:

```
{
   title: {'fr':'mon titre', 'en': 'my title', 'de': 'mein Titel'}
   description: { 'fr': 'ma description', /*...*/}
}
```

and I'm not sure how to display them:

1. I will have a lot of `ngFor` iterating on observable of those items, if I could avoid to having to map every data, it would be great
2. when the language change, I also need to have the correct translation displayed

What would you recommend me?

Answer (score 2):

The library [@ngx-translate/http-loader](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) allows loading the translations using http.

Bellow is an example of how I use `ngx-translate` along with `http-loader` in the applications I develop.

I have made a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwcrvy?file=src/app/translation-http-loader.ts) of the code bellow (available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwcrvy?file=src/app/translation-http-loader.ts)):

**Defining the data structure for the i18n strings**

In that example, for each language there is a url where the translation data (`json`) can be retrieved in the following format:

```
{
  welcome: "Welcome",
  subscription_msg: "Subscribe now"
}
```

**Creating one webservice for each supported language**

Consider one application that supports 3 languages: `en`, `pt` and `fr`.

I usually have one url for each language. Each url returns a json with `key` - `value` pairs where the keys are the labels I use in the frontend, and the values are the messages I want to show the users in that language.

In that example, I have create 3 mock urls with the translations for each language as follows:

English - Mock url: https://run.mocky.io/v3/33f736b0-e73a-499e-8a50-01e66041d634

```
{
  welcome: "Welcome",
  subscription_msg: "Subscribe now"
}
```

Portuguese - Mock url: https://run.mocky.io/v3/db1e37da-342e-4918-8ce2-bd30aa12fe79

```
{
  welcome: "Bem-vindo",
  subscription_msg: "Inscreva-se gratuitamente"
}
```

French - Mock url: https://run.mocky.io/v3/6960c960-ea66-42a0-87f1-f34568ecb740

```
{
  welcome: "Bienvenue",
  subscription_msg: "Abbonez-vous"
}
```

To output the `subscription_msg` in the frontend, I use the `ngx-translate` syntax like that:

```
{{ 'subscription_msg' | translate}}
```

**Installing @ngx-translate/http-loader**

Assuming `ngx-translate` is already installed, this is the command for installing `http-loader`:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

**Creating your own TranslationLoader**

We need to make an implementaion of `TranslationLoader` interface. It has just one method (`getLanguage()`) which is responsible for loading the map of i18n messages for the current language.

Bellow is our simple implementation called `TranslationHttpLoader`. It is invoked when the language is changed:

```
export class TranslationHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {
    if (lang == null) {
      lang == "en";
    }

    let urls = {
      en: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/33f736b0-e73a-499e-8a50-01e66041d634",
      pt: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/db1e37da-342e-4918-8ce2-bd30aa12fe79",
      fr: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/6960c960-ea66-42a0-87f1-f34568ecb740"
    };

    let observer = new Observable(observer => {
      this.httpClient.get(urls[lang]).subscribe(
        data => {
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
        }
      );
    });
    return observer;
  }
}
```

**Configuring the translation provider**

In the `app.module.ts` we should define a `HttpLoaderFactory`:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslationHttpLoader(httpClient);
}
```

and associate it with the provided `TranslateLoader`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Testing - changing language and showing localized messages**

To test

- we create a simple component that has a `<select>` with the languages as options and a `(change)` event handler.
- to output localized strings, we use the `ngx-translate` syntax `{{ 'key_in_json_file' | translate }}`.

*app.component.html*

```
<div>
    <label>Language</label>
    <select (change)="changeLanguage($event)">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="pt">Português</option>
    <option value="fr">Français</option>
  </select>

    <p>
        {{'welcome' | translate}}.
    </p>
    <p>
        {{'subscription_msg' | translate}}
    </p>
</div>
```

When the `(change)` event takes place, all we have to do is to call `translate.use(lang)`. Our loader will retrieve the data for the selected language in the url provided and will supply it to `ngx-translate`:

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent {
  defaultLang: string = "en";

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.translateService.use(this.defaultLang);
  }
  changeLanguage(event) {
    let lang = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.translateService.use(lang);
  }
}
```

**Output preview**

[image: Output preview for the 3 languages]

**Next steps**

Some enhacements can be done in the code provided here, for example:

- Detect browser language on user first access using `translateService.getBrowserLang()`
- Store the user current language in localstorage or other persistent storage.
- Adapt the `TranslationHttpLoader` so it can work offline with default tokens for each language (especially useful in mobile applications).

The code described above can be seen working here in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwcrvy?file=src/app/translation-http-loader.ts

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer, but I'm not sure it applies to me. I'm getting data from firebase, so I need to use the ngfire package to access my data(It allows to automatically manage synchronization between backend and frontend, allows to work offline and then synchronize, ...), so I cannot use the HttpLoader :(. Also, I'm not sure what would be the key? It's really about having localized business data on my backend, like if tripadvisor was having localized description.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to define the data you can get from your backend then probably you can make the data structure as below,

```
{
    "dataLocalization": [{
                            "locale": "fr",
                            "title": "mon titre",
                            "description":"ma description"
                        },
                        {
                            "locale": "en",
                            "title": "my title",
                            "description":"my description"
                        }]
}
```

Then you can find your locale by findIndex method in the array dataLocalization and use its title and description values

Comment: Check this way, let me know if you have any more query, if you found this useful mark it as correct, and please upvote

Comment: Yes, but how will this get changed if the user switch language

Comment: you will have this data received from your firebase stored somewhere right? whenever the user changes the language on the subscription of change where you might be using translate.use there  you need to again check this array and change values according to this array

Comment: yes, but what would be the best way to handle changes from the ngx-translate + changes coming from firebase?